# My spider doesn't follow links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
class KextraSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "kextra"
    allowed_domains = ["k-extra.fi"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/"]
    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('\?id=5&amp;epslanguage=fi&amp;sivu=\d')) , callback="parse_items" , follow=True),
    )


    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        kxitems = []
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="offerListItem"]')
        for site in sites:
            item = KextraItem()
            item["image"] = site.xpath('div[@class="offerListLeftColumn"]/img/@ src').extract()
            item["product_primary"] = site.xpath('div[@class="offerListRightColumn"]/h4/text()').extract()
            item["product_secondary"]= site.xpath('div[@class="offerListRightColumn"]/h3/text()').extract()
            item["discount"] = site.xpath('div[@class="offerListRightColumn"]/div[@class="plussaDiscount"]/div[@class="plussaAmount"]/text()').extract()
            item["priceEuros"] = site.xpath('div[@class="offerListPriceContainer"]/div[@class="price"]/p[@class="euros"]/text()').extract()
            item["priceCents"] = site.xpath('div[@class="offerListPriceContainer"]/div[@class="price"]/p[@class="euros"]/span[@class="cents"]/text()').extract()
            kxitems.append(item)
        return kxitems;
```

The problem is that the specified allow doesn't get followed. If i leave allow blank then whole links are followed . What could be the problem with regular expression in allow ?

Comment: Try changing "&amp;" to "&"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this link extractor:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('\?id=5&epslanguage=fi&sivu=\d'))
```

Example scrapy shell session:

```
paul@wheezy:~/$ scrapy shell http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.23.0 started (bot: scrunchscraper)
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrunchscraper.spiders', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 16, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrunchscraper.spiders'], 'TEMPLATES_DIR': 'templates/', 'BOT_NAME': 'scrunchscraper', 'WEBSERVICE_ENABLED': False, 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, CoreStats, SpiderState, StatsNotifier
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ConsistencyPipeline
2014-02-08 17:13:07+0100 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-02-08 17:13:08+0100 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/>
[s]   sel        <Selector xpath=None data=u'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtm'>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=<module 'scrunchscraper.settings' from '/home/paul/scrapinghub/scrunch/retailspiders/scrunchscraper/settings.pyc'>>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x387f950>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor                         

In [2]: SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('\?id=5&amp;epslanguage=fi&amp;sivu=\d')).extract_links(response)
Out[2]: []

In [3]: SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('\?id=5&epslanguage=fi&sivu=\d')).extract_links(response)
Out[3]: 
[Link(url='http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/?epslanguage=fi&id=5&sivu=1', text=u'2', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/?epslanguage=fi&id=5&sivu=2', text=u'3', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.k-extra.fi/Tarjoukset/?epslanguage=fi&id=5&sivu=6', text=u'Viimeinen', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In [4]:
```